# Tennis: when score is even they say: thirty (ou) or five games (ou)

Tags: grammar, expressions

Tennis: when score is even they say: thirty (ou) or five games (ou). Not sure about the right spelling for what is inside the brackets. I believe this is something came from French. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't mean the phrase "thirty all", do you? The exception being when it's 40-40, which is "deuce".

Comment: If it possible that for the French connection you are thinking of the use of 'Love' for 'no points' which apparently comes from 'l'oeuf' because a zero resembles an egg?

Answer (score 3):

They aren't actually saying 'ou', they are saying 'Thirty All'. The problem you're having is that person saying its accent is too thick.

[All](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/all)

> each; apiece:
> *The score was one all.*

*Dictionary.com*